# How to access `AWTAccessor.getCursorAccessor().setPData()`

Tags: java, illegalaccessexception

I'm trying to run `AWTAccessor.getCursorAccessor().setPData(this, cursor);` for a cursor related operation for the class `sun.awt.AWTAccessor`.

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class xawtcursor.XImageCursor (in unnamed module @0x3d3fcdb0) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAccessor (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x3d3fcdb0
    at xawtcursor.XImageCursor.createNativeCursor(XImageCursor.java:25)
    ...
```

Some test code (the `1` is invalid here, but it's just to simplify the test code a bit so it can be reproduced):

```java
package xawtcursor;

import sun.awt.AWTAccessor;
import sun.awt.X11.XCustomCursor;
import sun.awt.X11.XToolkit;

import java.awt.*;

public class XImageCursor extends XCustomCursor {
    public XImageCursor(Image cursor, Point hotSpot, String name) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        super(cursor, hotSpot, name);
    }

    protected void createNativeCursor(Image im, int[] pixels, int width, int height, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot) {
        XToolkit.awtLock();
        try {
            AWTAccessor.getCursorAccessor().setPData(this, 1);
        } finally {
            XToolkit.awtUnlock();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED` which fixed one error. What's the compilation option to let me access this one?

Comment: This [may not work at all as of Java 17](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403).

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the heads up. That page says `--add-opens` is still available, so it'll still work hopefully. Removing access to the code really limits *Java* imo, as things like X11 cursors are really poorly implemented in the default toolkit. There will be no way to override them if they act this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just need to add multiple `--add-exports` options. Adding the following works:

```
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED
```